# MPAndroidChart: Barchart xAxis label not centered - why?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have the following code snipped where I create a bar chart.
It works fine, the only problem is that my X axis labels are not centered. They are aligned to the left of each bar. Can anyone help with some adjustments to the code to address this? I have found some similar questions but they have all related to group bar charts with multiple series.

```
        ArrayList barEntries = clsGraphs.barEntries(myCursor, intBars);
        final ArrayList barLabels = clsGraphs.getMonthsLabels();


        barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Count by Month");
        barDataSet.setColors(Color.BLUE);
        barDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        barDataSet.setValueTextSize(0f);
        barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        barData.setBarWidth(1f);
        barChartMth.setData(barData);
        barChartMth.setDescription(null);
        barChartMth.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        YAxis rightYAxis = barChartMth.getAxisRight();
        rightYAxis.setEnabled(false);

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setLabelCount(barLabels.size());
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(0);

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

                if(value >= 0) {

                    if(value <= barLabels.size() - 1) {
                        int intVal = (int) value;
                        return String.valueOf(barLabels.get(intVal));
                    }
                    return "";
                }
                return "";

            }
        });
```